# Why do I keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range"?

Tags: python

I don't understand why I am getting this error when I don't believe I am looping out of bounds. The error appears to be in `x = lowercase[i + self.num]`

```
class Cipher:
        def __init__(self, string, num):
            self.string = string
            self.num = num
    
    def encrypt(self):
        lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                     'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
        uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'
                     'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        # establish the array from the inputed string
        split = []
        for x in range(len(self.string)):
            split.append(self.string[x])

        for x in split:
            for i in range(len(lowercase)):
                if (x == lowercase[i]):
                    x = lowercase[i + self.num]
                    print(x)


test = Cipher("hello", 1)
test.encrypt()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message. It tells you _where_ you get the error.

Comment: Agreed about posting the traceback but otherwise, well written question.

Comment: just added the error

Comment: For your reference, `string.ascii_uppercase` and `string.ascii_lowercase` contain all upper-case and lower-case letters, no need to type them.

Comment: thanks I'll definitely use this now lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no letter after `Z` (or `z`). You have to designate the "next" letter, which is usually `A` (and `a`). Therefore, `[i + self.num]` must be `[(i + self.num) % len(lowercase)]`. The modulo operator wraps the search around.

Comment: why does the value of split never change if the value of x does?

Comment: `x` is a _copy_ of an element in `split`.

Comment: how would I change the actual split and not make a copy?

Comment: You cannot. Strings are immutable in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`x = lowercase[i + self.num]` raised index Error if `i=25 and self.num=2`, so you should use `x = lowercase[(i + self.num)%26]`

In addition, `split = list(self.string)` is the better method if you want to convert string to list.

Comment: and maybe this is what you want `encrypted_string= "".join([lowercase[lowercase.index(x) + self.num] for x in list(self.string)])`